# generate a dynamic query with variable column numbers in where condition

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with Below Data in SQL SERVER

```
Key  SCH_NME TBL_NME    COLM_NME
---  ------  -------     ------------- 
PRM  DBO     Test       Col1,col2,col3
FRN  CHK     Tab          Col4,Col5
```

Please get me a dynamic query  to get an output in below format

```
select col1,col2,col3 from DBO.[Test] where (col1 is null OR col2 is null OR col3 is null;)
```

OR

```
select col4,col5 from CHK.[Tab] where (col4 is null OR col5 is null)
```

where Condition will be populated based on the COLM_NME (vaiable)

Comment: You can't separate where predicate with a comma. You need to have a logcial operator between predicates. This would need to have OR or AND. As posted this doesn't make a lot of sense and shows very little to no effort in trying to find a solution.

Comment: Hi Sean , I have Edited the Question

Comment: Great so have you tried anything? This is a horrible way to handle data in any database. It will require dynamic sql for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This screams of very poor design but the actual code is pretty simple. You need dynamic sql for this to work. I also had to generate the table based on your sample data provided.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    MyKey char(3)
    , SCH_NME char(3)
    , TBL_NME varchar(10)
    , COLM_NME varchar(100)
)

insert #Something
select 'PRM', 'DBO', 'Test', 'Col1,col2,col3' union all
select 'FRN', 'CHK', 'Tab', 'Col4,Col5'


--Now for the actual code.

Declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
    , @TblName sysname = 'Test'

select @SQL = 'select ' + COLM_NME + ' from [' + SCH_NME + '].[' + TBL_NME + '] where ' + REPLACE(COLM_NME, ',', ' IS NULL OR ') + ' IS NULL;'
from #Something
where TBL_NME = @TblName

select @SQL
--uncomment below when you are ready to run this
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```